# How do I combine data accurately using python pandas between columns with shared column values?

Tags: python

Python may be the best bet for this.   My attempted solution is below.

sheet 1:

```
Names   Trophies
Scott   3
Jim     3
Ron     2
Bob     1
Jack    1
```

sheet 2:

```
Names   Age Hobby
Bob     1   fishing
Scott   4   math
Jim     6   chess
Ron     2   tennis
```

The desired result is this:

```
Names   Trophies Age    Hobby
Bob     1        1      fishing
Scott   3        4      math
Jim     3        6      chess
Ron     2        2      tennis
Jack    1        1
```

Basically, I want to match the names from both sheets together, and combine their data accurately.

python code:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('test.csv',index_col=0, usecols=[0, 1])
print(df1.head())

df2 = pd.read_csv('test.csv',index_col=0, usecols=[0,1,2,3,4,6])
print(df2.head())

df = pd.merge(df2, df1, right_on=['Names'], left_on=['Names'], how='inner')
```

This gives me this error:

> raise KeyError(key) KeyError: 'Names'

Data inside the csv:
[image: The data inside the csv]

Comment: what library are you using for reading the excel? This is quite a simple task using `openpyxl` or `pandas`

Comment: Please don't ask a new duplicate question... instead address the answer posted at the [original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59862659/how-do-i-find-matches-in-excel-columns-then-write-the-matching-data-to-a-new-she).

Comment: Besides, VLOOKUP will do this.

Comment: pandas yes, i plan on attempting to do it using pandas.

Comment: yes VLOOKUP can but how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combination of INDEX and MATCH formulas will work in MS Excel

For examples to get the AGE values in your desired result you conceptually do this:

```
=INDEX(X; MATCH(Y;Z))
```

X stands for the range of values that you want to fetch from sheet 2, so in this case your column 'AGE' from sheet 2

Y stands for the name value in sheet 1

Z stands for the range of values in sheet 2 in which you want to look for Y. So in this case your column 'NAMES' from sheet 2